# Unable to find where to translate certain tooltip string

Tags: localization

I am working with the Store Shopline theme on Woocommerce, and am trying to set up a version which is localised to German.

This is going ok, however, I can't seem to get a hold of the text string displayed on a certain tooltip. The string reads "Register", and I would like to translate it as "Registrieren".

[image]

Interestingly enough, the tooltip for the shopping cart icon just to the right of the register icon **is** translated, using a German translation installed along with Woocommerce on my server.

I have installed LocoTranslate, and found a string "Register" in this translation file, however, translating this string only changed the localisation in the title for my registration form (not pictured in above screenshot).

I have searched (grep) every folder I could think of on the server in folder home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs for 'Register', but was not able to pin dow the exact location of this text string.

How can I translate this text string from "Register" to "Registrieren" for the German version of this site?

Comment: this text is defined in the function `shopline_my_account` in the file `plugins/themehunk-customizer/shopline/woo/woocommerce.php`. but before to customise that, you have another problem : "Store Shopline" is a child theme then you cannot edit its files. either you rename the directory `store-shopline` to stop the updates of this theme, or ... you choose another theme !